# Codeigniter upload library to validate min width and min height of image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using upload library in codeigniter to upload image….....

```
$config[‘allowed_types’]    = ‘gif|png|jpg’;
$config[‘max_size’]      = ‘1000’;
$config[‘max_width’]      = ‘200’;
$config[‘max_heigth’]      = ‘200’;
$config[‘upload_path’]    = ‘./uploads/’
$this->load->library(‘upload’, $config);
```

while user uploading image….....user should upload minimum widht and minimum height

for this how to do…......

CI have only max_width and max_heigth…......  I am aware about this function as well

```
 getimagesize();
```

but to use this function we need source image url... which i dont have access to...

Comment: Before or after upload ?

Answer (score 3):

To do this use next piece of code:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($data['full_path']);
```

You should use JavaScript to determine the file's size before it gets uploaded, because PHP can't do it as it is server side rather than client.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but this will give size after upload. I need for validate image before uploading.

Comment: Use client side languages such as javascript. You should understand that server-side can't measure image side on the client ;)